# Open a local .html on extension mouse click

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating my first chrome extension. When the extension icon is clicked, I wish that chrome will open a new tab, and open there a local .html page I have created.

Following the instructions on Google's documentation, I have created the following:

**manisfest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Notes",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "ninjaicon.png",
    "default_popup": "notes.html"
},

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

  "permissions": [
    "tabs"
 ]
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
  chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('notes.html')}, function(tab)
  });
});
```

When I press my extensions icon, there is a popup with "notes.html" content, but no new tab is opened like I wished.

How am I suppose to do it correctly? been looking up on a lot of solutions here but non worked.
I just wish to create an extension that when clicked opens a new tab with a local web application.

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: have you tried to remove `"default_popup"` part from `browser_action`

Comment: I have tried to create another .html file, and call this new .html from the background.js.. didn't work also.

Comment: Also tried to remove it completely (having no pop up), still doesn't work..

Comment: have you reloaded the extension after remove "default_popup"?

Comment: Yes. I have reloaded it and it's not working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this to work, the `notes.html` should be in your extension's root directory.

Remove the `default_popup` from the manifest file as

> The onClicked event is fired when a browser action icon is clicked but this event will not fire if the browser action has a popup as it overrides this event.

This is mentioned in the documentation [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), scroll to the last to read the same.

Also, have you tried to see your background page's console. I see the code you have written is wrong. There is no opening brace in your `chrome.tabs.create` callback function. Fix it if you want to add code to your callback function, if not you can simply write like this:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('notes.html')});
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: The most important part (conceptually) is that `onClicked` and a popup set with `default_popup` can't work together - a popup overrides `onClicked` listeners. It would be great if you could explain that better in your answer.

Comment: @Xan Yes I should be explaining that. Thanks. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

there is two way to open your local html page by the browser action.

### 1. As a popup

**manifest.json**

```
"browser_action":   {
                            "default_icon"  :   "128.png",
                            "default_popup" :   "localPage.html",
                            "default_title" :   "localPage title"
                        }
```

### 2. As a normal page in chrome browser

**manifest.json**

```
"background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function () {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.runtime.getURL("localpage.html") });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, it is worth to mention that you don't need `"permissions": ["tabs"]` to open a static html page from the extension folder

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(function() {
  chrome.tabs.create({url: 'index.html'});
});
```