# Javascript - Open HTML File In Same Tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a [[image]google-chrome-extension](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-extension) where you click a button and it opens a local HTML file in the same tab that the button was clicked in, essentially redirecting the current page to the file. I can't seem to find the way to do this.

Currently, I have it opening as a whole separate window with:

```
chrome.windows.create({
    url: chrome.runtime.getURL(request.pageURL),
    type: "popup"
}, function (window) {});
```

How can I get the same page to show up in the tab it's executed from?

Thanks!

Comment: May be duplicate of this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846565/open-a-local-html-on-extension-mouse-click

Comment: Simply use chrome.tabs.update, see the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! That works great!